# Possible deadlock: ANR debugging

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I have only recently started looking into ANR issues on android. I have a high level idea of what ANR is what could be its possible reasons. In the issue that I am working on however, I am not able to decipher as to what is exactly the problem. Relevant parts of ANR traces are as follows:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415f6e58 self=0x41516828
  | sysTid=1035 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074409812
  | state=S schedstat=( 2593876942 1100275957 4673 ) utm=190 stm=69 core=0
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:~13826)
  - waiting to lock <0x41a81f00> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService) held by tid=59 (Binder_C)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.broadcastStickyIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:96)
  at com.android.server.BatteryService$8.run(BatteryService.java:591)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1259)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1360)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


"Binder_C" prio=5 tid=59 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ae9e00 self=0x6247bb78
  | sysTid=1508 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1648867632
  | state=S schedstat=( 318123480 187097758 1551 ) utm=26 stm=5 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41e6fc90> (a com.android.server.PermissionDialogResult$Result)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at com.android.server.PermissionDialogResult$Result.get(PermissionDialogResult.java:40)
  at com.android.server.AppOpsService.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:651)
  at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:778)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:13941)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:383)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2083)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Clearly, the main thread is waiting to get lock held by binder_C but I am not getting what exactly is binder_C waiting for. Could this be a deadlock issue? Also for the binder thread, what does the "WAIT" tag (on first line) signify?

Comment: Were you able to figure out anything on this? I'm having a similar issue